# Subselect fetching causing unexpected interaction between seemingly unrelated lines of code

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Tomcat web application that uses Hibernate. In a very simplified version of the object model, I have three classes: `Employee`, `Foo`, and `Bar`. `Employee` has a one-to-many relation with both `Foo` and `Bar`. `Foo` has a many-to-one relation with many other unnamed objects in the system.

While processing a particular page request, my application will (all within a single Hibernate session):

```
Employee emp = session.get(Employee.class, id);
List<Foo> foos = session.createCriteria(Foo.class).add(eq("emp", emp)).list();
for (Bar bar : emp.getBars()) bar.doStuff();
```

In actuality these three lines are very far apart and actually in separate source files. In particular, line 1 is run on every single request (it gets the logged-in user), line 2 gets the data of interest for the problematic page, and line 3 gets some data that is shown on every page in a sidebar.

Also note that `bar.doStuff()` actually traverses a few more levels away from `Bar` in the object graph (each employee is actually assigned to some clients who have some projects that have some tasks).

Within line 2, everything runs smoothly and the SQL generated when we iterate over `emp.getBars()` is nice and simple, just `select stuff where Bar.empID = ?`. The further subselects for the children of the `Bar`s do have increasingly many subqueries, but objectively don't take a noticeable amount of time and I assume MySQL is smart enough to optimize them.

However, when line 2 is executed between lines 1 and 3, line 3 takes a very long time. After looking at the generated SQL, I am certain this is related to the subselect behavior and the fact that `Foo` has so many *ToOne relations.

The query for line 2 has a LOT of both outer and inner joins, since Hibernate doesn't actually support subselect fetching on *ToOne relations. When the line 2 query is run, it necessarily retrieves `emp` again. Of course, Hibernate *notices* that it has already retrieved `emp`, and so does not actually construct a new `Employee` object, instead assigning the already-created instance to the field inside each `Foo`.

The problem is that now the most recent query that "retrieved" `emp` was a big ugly query with a lot of joins. Thus when we try to get all of its `Bar`s, the generated SQL is now of the form: `select stuff from Bar where Bar.empID in (select Foo.empID from Foo join many tables)`.

And of course this problem gets repeated several times over as we proceed deeper into the object graph from `Bar`. The end result is that the page takes almost thirty seconds to load.

I could solve the problem in this particular instance by forcing initialization of `emp.getBars()` early, but this seems like a bad solution because:

1. It's hacky and non-obvious
2. We may run into the problem again with another class or field and have to diagnose all over again

I am genuinely stumped regarding the right way to deal with this. Has anyone else run into this and come up with a good solution?

EDIT: per request here is (a stylized version of) my mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Employee
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "emp")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Set<Bar> bars = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Foo
{
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "empID")
    private Employee emp;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "class1_ID")
    private Class1 class1;
    // repeat for Class2, 3, 4, etc.
    // some are nullable, others not
}

@Entity
public class Bar // Bar represents an employee being assigned to a client
{
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "empID")
    private Employee emp;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientID")
    private Client client;
    // Client itself has-many Projects which have-many Tasks
    // which are all themselves mapped entities and the objects we ultimately want
}
```

Comment: Can you show the mapping for the problem objects?

Comment: Not the full mapping because it would be far too long for SO, but I'll put up a stylized version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Given that your Foo and Bar have a lot of many-to-one relations, I'd recommend trying using lazy fetching, note using fetch=LAZY below:

   @Entity
   public class Foo
   {
       @ManyToOne(fetch=LAZY, optional = false)
       @JoinColumn(name = "empID")
       private Employee emp;

   ```
   @ManyToOne(fetch=LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "class1_ID")
   private Class1 class1;
   // repeat for Class2, 3, 4, etc.
   // some are nullable, others not
   ```

   }
2. An better performing alternative of getting and traversing the relations though mapped fields is a direct JPA/Hibirante query to get what you need for further processing. This why hibernate won't have to work hard to build the object tree but instead you'll get what you want with a single query. For instance, using pseudo-code:

   List resultSet = session.createQuery("select b.employee.name, b.employee.phone from Bar b where b.client.name = ?).setString(0, "blah").list();
3. I also recommend enabling second level and query caching.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Slava Imeshev